# How to convert printed table into data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, certain functions output data by printing in the console, instead of creating objects. This is inconvenient for further analysing the output or moving it to another application. I have encountered this in the reclassification function in "PredictABEL".

For example, the following prints 3 large tables which I am unfortunately unable to assign to an object.

```
reclassification(data = data, cOutcome = 1, predrisk1 = predictor1, predrisk2 = predictor2, cutoff = seq(0,1,0.1))
```

I don't think the details are important, but in the interests of making this example reproducible, below are the variables used in the above arguments

```
data = data.frame(outcome = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1), predictor1 = c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,0.5), predictor2 = c(0.5,1.5,2,0,0.5,2,0,0.5))
mod1 <- glm(outcome ~ predictor1, data = data, family = binomial(link="logit"))
mod2 <- glm(outcome ~ predictor2, data = data, family = binomial(link="logit"))
predictor1 <- predict(mod1, data, type = "response")
predictor2 <- predict(mod2, data, type = "response")
```

Is anyone able to explain how I can assign my output to an object, preferably in neat tabular format that is amenable to further analysis?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use capture.output() which will capture the results as character vector. Then you can extract the tables from it.

```
out<- capture.output(reclassification(data = data, cOutcome = 1, predrisk1 = predictor1, predrisk2 = predictor2, cutoff = seq(0,1,0.1)))
```